# How to Create a file at a specific path in python?

Tags: python

I am writing below code which is not working:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
log = path.join(cwd,'log.out')
os.chdir(cwd) and  Path(log.out).touch() and os.chmod(log.out, 777)
```

how can I create a log.out into cwd ?

Comment: Can it have random data in it?

Comment: Yes, I just need a random file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an empty file:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(cwd)
filename = 'log.out' 
with open(os.path.join(cwd, filename), 'wb') as f:
    f.write('')
os.chmod(filename, 777)
```

This will create an empty file called `log.out`, which of course will be content-empty, but that can easily change with the use of the `f.write(content)` function.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the usual linux `touch` command via `subprocess`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["touch", cwd+"/log.out"])
```